# OpenCV find all significant edges along a line

Tags: image, opencv, labview, edge-detection

I have an image that I used to analyze in LabView using a method called Rake. Basically, what that method does is it finds all the significant edges along parallel lines on an image.
http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370281P-01/imaqvision/imaq_rake_3/ (as seen on the last image at the bottom of the link).
The beauty of this function is that it will give you all edge points that are larger than a certain edge strength, and each edge will only generate one edge point (thickness of the edge line is 1 pixel)

I want to use OpenCV to do something similar. The way I could imagine for doing this is 
- deconstructing the Canny operator with a filter of my choice,
- hysterisis thresholding of the edge values with two thresholds
- followed by nonmaxima suppression
- read the pixels along that line and mark all pixels that are larger than my threshold

the problem is that the canny comes as a bundle and I cant find the nonmaxima suppression function by itself.
Does anybody know of a way to do something similar to the operation I've described?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand this question fully, but about the unbundled non-maximum suppression part:

One simple way for 2d non-maximum suppression is this:
dilate the image. Dilation in OpenCV sets the value of each pixel to the max() of the local neighborhood. Repeat a few times or use a larger kernel to get the desired radius.

Then compare the dilated image with the original and set all pixels with differing values to zero.

The remaining pixels are local maxima.

```
 # some code I once used in OpenCV/Python
 # given an image, sets all pixels to zero, unless they are local maxima
 def supressNonMaxima(img):
     localMax = cvCreateImage (cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_16U, 1)
     cvDilate(img, localMax, null, 3)  # max() with radius of 3

     mask = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), 8, 1)
     cvCmp(img, localMax, mask, CV_CMP_LT)

     cvSet(img,0,mask)
```